Subtlety of identifying $W^{k,p}\bigl([0,1] \bigr)$ and $W^{k,p}(S^1)$
Let $k \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ and $p \in [1.\infty]$. Then, I wonder if it is possible to identify the two Sobolev spaces
\begin{equation}
W^{k,p}\bigl([0,1] \bigr) \text{ and } W^{k,p}(S^1)
\end{equation}
For $k=0$, it is trivial, so the subtlety seems to arise from weak derivatives.
According to this MO post, weak derivatives of functions on $[0,1]$ can be defined just by using smooth functions on the open interval $(0,1)$ with compact supports.
However, $S^1 := \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}$ is a compact smooth manifold without boundary. So it is not clear to me how to actually define $W^{k,p}(S^1)$. That is, should we use periodic smooth functions to define weak derivatives on $S^1$? Such choice of test functions is apparently more general than those on $(0,1)$ with compact supports.
Could anyone please help me with this subtle and confusing issue?

Perhaps one exercise might be to ask why $W^{k,p}(0,1)$ is not naturally identifiable with $W^{k,p}( (0,\frac{1}{2})\cup(\frac{1}{2}, 1))$. (Define the latter space as the closure of  smooth functions on $(0,1)$ whose support does not contain $\frac{1}{2}$).

Of course it is not possible, since these spaces are not the same. The function $f(\theta) = \theta$ is in $W^{1,1}([0, 1])$ but not in $W^{1, 1} (S^1)$.
This is a manifestation of the failure of the fundamental theorem of calculus to hold on manifolds in general, which is captured by de Rham cohomology.

Apparently, we can change the value of $f$ at the endpoints to make it look periodic.. this is another source of confusion.

What is the exact definition of a Sobolev space on $S^1$? I think this must be made clear first.

I think you can find that in standard texts, though I don’t have a reference in mind right now.

In any case, I am not sure if de Rham cohomology is suitable in this context. It pertains to smooth functions, but I am dealing with measure-theoretic settings.

Well, I think your example works: My own MO post.
